# gawk system-command ignoring backslashes

Tags: gawk

Consider a file with a list of strings,

```
string1
string2
...
abc\de
```

.

When using gawk's system command to execute a shell command
, in this case printing the strings,

```
cat file | gawk '{system("echo " $0)}'
```

the last string will be formatted to abcde. $0 denotes the whole record, here this is just the one string

Is this a limitation of gawk's system command, not being able to output the gawk variables unformatted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on Mussé Redi's answer, observe that, in the following, the backslash does not print:

```
$ echo 'abc\de' | gawk '{system("echo " $0)}'
abcde
```

However, here, the backslash will print:

```
$ echo 'abc\de' | gawk '{system("echo \"" $0 "\"")}'
abc\de
```

The difference is that the latter command passes `$0` to the shell with double-quotes around it.  The double-quotes change how the shell processes the backslash.

The exact behavior will change from one shell to another.

To print while avoiding all the shell vagaries, a simple solution is:

```
$ echo 'abc\de' | gawk '{print $0}'
abc\de
```

Comment: The original problem was to use the rm command to remove a list of files. Hence the system command of gawk was necessary.

Comment: I actually thaught that the $0 variable of gawk was different then the $0 variable of Bash, so I did not consider your solution with the double backslashes around $0. Since we then will be referring to the $0 variable of Bash.

Comment: @MusséRedi Yes, the `$0` of gawk is different and unrelated to the `$0` of shell.  When `awk` sees `"echo " $0`, it concatenates `echo ` with the contents of awk's `$0`.  The resulting string is then passed to the shell.

Comment: Aha I see, so our string will be passed to the shell in double-quotess just as you said. \" of course denotes a double quote.

Answer (score 0):

In Bash we use double backslashes to denote an actual backslash. The function of a single backslash is *escaping* a character. Hence the system command is not formatting at all; Bash is.

The solution for this problem is writing a function in awk to preformat backslashes to double backslahses, afterwards passing it to the system command.